# Yii2: Pretty URL Rule to allow garbage data in URL

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, datatables, yii2

I am using URL Rewriting rules and URL manager on my project. This is the code of my URLManager rules:

```
        'rules' => [
            '/'=>'site/index',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<type:(admin|driver|user)>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<type:(admin|driver|user)>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<type:(admin|driver|user)>/<_:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
        ],
```

The problem is that DataTables is sending data with an extra parameter in the URL `?_=1474714889055` which is messing everything. I added the last line of code to allow this param or any other garbage data that Datatable adds.

How to remove this code or allow it to be in the URL without affecting the routing?

Regards

EDIT:

```
public function actionVerified()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $expression = new \yii\db\Expression('CONCAT(`driver_details`.`first_name`, " ", `driver_details`.`last_name`) as `driver_name`');
    $bookings = \app\models\Bookings::find()
    ->select(["bookings.*",
        "TIME_FORMAT(booking_start, '%h:%i %p') as booking_start",
        "TIME_FORMAT(booking_end, '%h:%i %p') as booking_end",
        "users_main.name as verified_by_name",
        "user_details.name as booked_by", 
        "user_details.contact as contact", 
        new \yii\db\Expression("CONCAT('STARWAY-BKNG-',bookings.id) as id_show"),
        $expression
    ])->joinWith('userDetail')
    ->joinWith('driverDetail')
    ->joinWith('usersMain')
    ->where(['verified'=>1, 'canceled'=> 0, 'completed'=>0])->asArray()->all();
    foreach ($bookings as $key => $booking) {
        unset($booking['userDetail']);
        unset($booking['driverDetail']);
        unset($booking['usersMain']);
        $booking_send[] = $booking;
    }
    if(!isset($booking_send)){
        $booking_send = [];
    }
    return $booking_send;
}
```

Comment: `?_=1474714889055` should not affect anything, unless you have a dependency on `_` in your action. Because that's just a query parameter which you can totally ignore if you don't need it. Can you show us your action where it is messing you things??

Comment: @leninhasda this is the URL `http://project.local/api/booking/verified/admin/?_=1474714889055` and im getting 404 with this `?_` and if i remove it, url works

Comment: Ok, i tried to recreate your issue: made a `api` module, made a 'Booking' controller, inside that made a `verified` method with just one line on it `echo 'hello';`. Then i added your `rules` (without the list line) in my config file and it still works using url like yours: `http://localhost/yii2-test/api/booking/verified/admin/?_=147471488‌​9055`. Can you show your `verified` method?

Comment: i am updating my answer with the verified action code

Comment: @leninhasda would you be able to share your .htaccess code?

Comment: i kinda fixed it... just realized this was regex... so I added this rule: `'<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<type:(admin|driver|user)>/<_:\*?>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',`. But is it a good fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i know why you are getting 404 error. It's  the last '/' part, just before '?_=147471488‌​9055', which is causing 404.

According to Yii2 following these two URLs are different:

```
// these two are not same
http://domain.com/controller/action
http://domain.com/controller/action/
```

And you will find several discussions on [Yii Github Issues](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues) page if you just search with `trailing slash`.

I don't know where that last `/` was coming from so i checked [DataTables Documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) but didn't find any last '/' on their example code or ajax url:

```
// their ajax code 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'
    } );
} );

// ajax url being called in their example page
https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/data/arrays.txt?_=1474729703286
```

So I'm guessing you might have a type somewhere on your source code which is adding that last `/`. Fixing that should solve your issue.

If however this wasn't the case, you can try to use following rules in your config:

```
'rules' => [
    '/'=>'site/index',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
    '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<type:(admin|driver|user)>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
    '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<type:(admin\/|driver\/|user\/)>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>', // allow the trailing slash 
    '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<type:(admin|driver|user)>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
],
```

Although your current solution worked, but I am not recommending

```
'<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<type:(admin|dri‌​ver|user)>/<_:\*?>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>'
```

this rule because it's incorrect. `<_:\*?>`part means the following URLs are also allowed:

```
// .......................................^ these are definitely not valid.
YOUR_DOMAIN/module/controller/action/type/*
YOUR_DOMAIN/module/controller/action/type/?
YOUR_DOMAIN/module/controller/action/type/*?
YOUR_DOMAIN/module/controller/action/type/?*
```

I hope you got my point.

And lastly, i am just using standard wordpress like `.htaccess` file. Here it is  just in case:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Yep you were right t was the trailing slash, but you know the most funny thing? It disappeared. Removing my 3rd rule now doesn't make a difference. -.-